# To fix scatter sizes in Excel (scatter plot made from Table)

Tags: excel, plot, scatter-plot

Small dataset in Excel as a Table. A slicer is added. And, I made a scatter plot from it.

The scatter size is set to larger than default but when I choose from slicer, the size of scatters jumped back to default size (smaller).

For example, Kate's in the screenshot.

What's the way to fix the scatter sizes?

[image]

[image]

[Excel file: Scatter plot.xlsx](https://ufile.io/d0l4gqwv)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select Kate > Select the graph > Format > Current Selection : Vertical/Horintal Axis > Try Fix the value here (no Auto)

Does it work on ur excel version?

Comment: thank you for your answer. When I Select Kate > Select the graph > Format > Current Selection, the Excel version doesn't show "Vertical/Horintal Axis". Shall I choose "Series Kate"? btw, strangely, I downloaded and opened the file I uploaded, the scatters seem all fine (no change of size anymore)